# Remote assets space issue storage/runtime/assets/sources

Tags: assets

I was wondering if someone could help me with the following issue:

I'm saving assets on Amazon S3 and as per Craft's documentation Craft is keeping a copy of remote assets in `storage/runtime/assets/sources` folder. The issue is that this website has a lot of images and `sources` folder in storage is taking up a lot of space. It can go up to 5GB.

Is there a way I can tell Craft to not keep a copy of remote assets?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can instruct Craft not to keep a local copy of remote assets by setting the [`maxCachedCloudImage` config variable](https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/config-settings.html#maxcachedcloudimagesize) to `0` (zero).

It may be worth experimenting with that setting, to find a balance between caching some smaller images locally (thereby speeding up transformations), and preserving disk space.